# Reduce Aviary SDK size

Tags: android, methods, dex, aviary

How can I reduce the aviary method count, by removing some unused features ?

Indeed, my app without the sdk reach 41696 methods, but with aviary, 56956, so more than 15K methods. It's huge, and shouldn't be that much.

Turns out that Aviary is using  "it.sephiroth.android.library" which already create 2253 methods.
If I want to integrate other sdk like facebook or inmobi, the 65K is quickly reached.

I tried with multi dex, but it turns out the app have some unknow bugs (trying to reach a method which is not in the same dex, and go "not found").
Check the part "limitations"
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Did anyone tried to strip it ?